# How to remove Task from collection after completed

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Let's say I have a collection of `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`:

```
HashSet<Task> myTasks = new HashSet<Task>();
```

...and I periodically feed more into the collection as I have more data that needs to be processed:

```
foreach (DataItem item in itemsToProcess)
    myTasks.Add(
        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => Process(item),
            cancellationToken,
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
            TaskScheduler.Default));
```

Since `Task`s remain in `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion` status after finishing instead of just disappearing, they would remain in the collection until explicitly removed and the collection would grow indefinitely.  The `Task`s need to be pruned to prevent this.

One approach I have looked at is giving the `Task` access to the collection and having it remove itself at the very end.  But I am also looking at an architecture where I would have to remove a Task that my component has not created.  My first thought is to attach a trigger or event to completion of each Task, something like this:

```
foreach (Task task in createdSomewhereElse)
{
    lock (myTasks) myTasks.Add(task);
    task.WhenTaskIsCompleted += 
        (o, ea) => { lock(myTasks) myTasks.Remove(task); };
    task.Start();
}
```

...but `Task` has no such event.  Is there any good way to accomplish what I'm looking for?  Something like this:

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You certainly *can* attach a trigger for when a task is completed: [`Task.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) (and its generic equivalent). That would probably be good enough for you.

You *may* also wish to use `ConcurrentDictionary` as a sort of poor-man's concurrent set - that way you wouldn't have to lock when accessing the collection. Just use the `Keys` property when iterating, and use anything you like as the value.

Comment: Jon, do you have a particular implementation of `ConcurrentHashSet` in mind? There's none built into the BCL that I'm aware of.

Comment: @LukeH: Doh - I was thinking of ConcurrentDictionary. Will edit :)

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I'm looking to do.  :)  So replacing the `+=` statement with `task.ContinueWith((t) => { lock(myTasks) myTasks.Remove(t); });` is correct?  Also, +1 on @LukeH's comment; I didn't see one of those in the system libraries.

Comment: Ahh, got excited for a second there... I'm actually using ConcurrentDictionary in the real code, but abstracted out to a HashSet to reduce the complexity of the question.

Comment: @Calvin: That looks correct to me, yes. ContinueWith is one of the things that the async support in C# 5 is built on :)

Comment: Question: Using `Task.ContinueWith` to remove a Task from a collection of active Tasks makes sense... _but_ `Task.ContinueWith` _also returns a new `Task`_ object, which then needs to be retained (for exception observability, etc) - and [in MS' own Console program example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__:~:text=continuationTask.Wait()) they show calling `continuationTask.Wait()`. So how should that be handled?

Comment: @Dai: I have to admit that I often just let the task returned by `ContinueWith` go unobserved unless I need it for timing. (I also have a helper method in personal code which logs exceptions but does nothing else.) My typical usage of ContinueWith is for things that are so trivial they "can't" go wrong mind you. I'm not necessarily recommending this as a strategy - just reporting what I actually do in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to keep the tasks in a collection?

Why not use a solution based on BlockingCollection and Parallel.ForEach

```
var sources = new BlockingCollection<DataItem>();

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    Parallel.ForEach(sources.GetConsumingPartitioner(),
                     item => Process(item));
});
```

Now you can just feed your items into the blocking collection and they will automatically be processed.

```
foreach (DataItem item in itemsToProcess)
    sources.Add(item);
```

You can use `sources.Count`and `foreach (DataItem item in sources)` to see non-processed items.
(A difference from your solution is that you can't see items currently processing)

Comment: Interesting alternative.  I'm keeping the Tasks in a collection so I can see how many are still processing, wait until all currently processing tasks are completed (`Task.WaitAll(myTasks.ToArray());`), and in real-life where I'm using a ConcurrentDictionary, to associate a data item with the Task that's processing it.

Comment: @adrianm, is there any wait to cancel specific task?

Comment: @Calvin, Nothing built in. Parallel.ForEach got some overloads that allows you to cancel remaining tasks. I would add a flag or cancellation token to the DataItem and check for cancel in Process()

Comment: Using Parallel.ForEach over a BlockingCollection is dangerous: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx

Comment: @Ronnie: If you read your own linked article you'll see that the solution is to use `.GetConsumingPartitioner` instead of `.GetConsumingEnumerable`. Then look at my code above.

Comment: @adrianm - You are right and I have read it. I missed that you were using GetConsumingPartitioner() in your code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) to set a action which removes the task from the set.